# Arranging physical disk sectors before writing to disk

Tags: c++, asynchronous, nosql, storage, acid

Bakcground:
I'm developing on the new [SparkleDB](http://sparkledb.net) NoSQL database, the database is ACID and has its own disk space manager (DSM) all for its database file storage accessing. The DSM allows for multiple thread concurrent I/O operations on the same physical file, ie. Asynchronous I/O or overlapped I/O. We disable disk caching, thus we write pages directly to the disk, as this is required for ACID databases.

My question is:
Is there a performance gain by arranging continuous disk page from many threads writes before sending the I/O request to the underlying disk OS I/O subsystem(thus merging the data to be written if they are continuous), or does the I/O subsystem do this for you? My question applies to UNIX, Linux, and Windows.

Example (all happends within a space of 100ms):

1. Thread #1: Write 4k to physical file address 4096
2. Thread #2: Write 4k to physical file address 0
3. Thread #3: Write 4k to physical file address 8192
4. Thread #4: Write 4k to physical file address 409600
5. Thread #5: Write 4k to physical file address 413696
6. Using this information, the DSM arranges a single 12kb write operation to physical file address 0, and a single 8kb write operation to physical file address 409600.

Update:
The DSM does all the physical file access address positioning on Windows by providing a `OVERLAPPED` structure, `io_prep_pwrite` on Linux AIO, and `aiocb`'s `aio_offset` on POSIX AIO.

Comment: Any performance-sensitive DB will run off a SSD, potentially with an additional HDD for the less sensitive I/O. On an SSD, "physical" addresses are invisible due to remapping.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient method to use a hard drive is to keep writing as much data as you can while the platters are still spinning.  This involves reducing the quantity of writes and increase the amount of data per write.  If this can happen, then having a disk area of continuous sectors will help.

For each write, the OS needs to translate the write to your file into logical or physical coordinates on the drive.  This may involve reading the directory, searching for your file and locating the mapping of your file within the directory.

After the OS determines the location, it sends data across the interface to the hard drive.  Your data may be cached along the way many times until it is placed onto the platters.  An efficient write will use the block sizes of the caches and data interfaces.

Now the questions are: 1) How much time does this save?  and 2) Is the time saving significant.  For example, if all this work saves you 1 second, this one second gained may be lost in waiting for a response from the User.

Many programs, OS and drivers will postpone writes to a hard drive to non-critical or non-peak periods.  For example, while you are waiting for User input, you could be writing to the hard drive.  This posting of writes may be less effort than optimizing the disk writes and have more significant impact to your application.

BTW, this has nothing to do with C++.

Comment: Our DSM does all the physical file access address positioning on Windows by providing a `OVERLAPPED` structure, `io_prep_pwrite` on Linux AIO, and `aiocb`'s `aio_offset` on POSIX AIO, is your answer still valid with this additionally provided information?